# php table display data, edit, delete

Tags: php, string

I have spent the entire day trying to get this code snippet to work:

```
    <?php
            include("conn.php");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");
  echo "<table border=\"0\" width=\"100%\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" id=\"product-       table\">
  <tr>
  <th class=\"table-header-check\"><a id=\"toggle-all\" ></a> </th>
  <th class=\"table-header-repeat line-left\" ><a href=\"\">User ID</a></th>
  <th class=\"table-header-repeat line-left\"><a href=\"\"> Username</a></th>
  <th class=\"table-header-repeat line-left\"><a href=\"\">Firstname</a></th>
  <th class=\"table-header-repeat line-left\"><a href=\"\">Lastname</a></th>
  <th class=\"table-header-repeat line-left\"><a href=\"\">Email</a></th>
  <th class=\"table-header-repeat line-left\"><a href=\"\">Registration Date</a></th>
  <th class=\"table-header-options line-left\"><a href=\"\">Options</a></th>
   </tr>";
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>"."<input  type=\"checkbox\"/></td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['user_id'] . "</td> ";
    echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['first_name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['last_name'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['registration_date'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td class=\"options-width\">".
                "<a href=\"\" title=\"Edit\" class=\"icon-1 info-tooltip\">              </a>".
                "><a href="delete.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '"class=\"icon-2 info-tooltip\"></a>".
                "<a href=\"\" title=\"Save\" class=\"icon-5**strong text**info-tooltip\">       </a>".
                "
                </td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }


     ?>
```

What im trying to do is pull my users into an html table, and then make it so i can edit/delete them from the url string ex.

Comment: Error message?  You have to give us more than that..

Comment: I want to populate delete.php? with the user_id in my mysql table. Its like my sytax is just off a little...

Comment: Would that happen to be because of your unescaped double quote at `<a href="delete.php...`?

Comment: Your code is inefficient in the task of displaying code, besides that, I see no error with the code and you are not supplying us with enough information to give a remotely useful answer. In addition to that, you shouldn't keep small scripts on seperate pages when they're only about 5 lines long and can be more efficient on that page.

Comment: Palladium, I just tried escaping it still no go :(

Comment: You should look into using templates/views.  Echoing out raw HTML is a sign of doing it wrong, and (as you've encountered) it makes it a lot harder to debug.  Echo data, not HTML.

Comment: @kevinmajor11 Although I'd agree in the circumstance that it's a user edit page, I wouldn't agree with you whilst doing tables as it adds more lines of code and doesn't look so pretty.

Comment: @PwnageAtPwn Huh?  Why would there be added code?  PHP is best written with all complex processing/db interactions done first, then output, which has just UI logic (echo, if/else, loops).  Far more concise, readable, easy to debug/edit/maintain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change before last echo by this line

```
            echo '<td class="options-width">'.
            '<a href="" title="Edit" class="icon-1 info-tooltip"> </a>'.
            '      <a href="delete.php?id=' . $row['id'] . ' " class="icon-2 info-tooltip"></a>'.
            '<a href="" title="Save" class="icon-5**strong text**info-tooltip">       </a>'.
            '</td>';
```

You have a problem with quotes (nested ones " and ' )

Comment: Thanks alot alibm. This is almost fixed now the only problem is i see a > after each table row.

Comment: @user1576685 : there's an extra > before a href tag; remove it as did and it's ok :)))

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is an answer, but it's cleaner and may be less prone to issues:

```
<?php
    include("conn.php");
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");
    $rows   = mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>
<table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="product-table">
    <tr>
        <th class="table-header-check"><a id="toggle-all"></a> </th>
        <th class="table-header-repeat line-left"><a href="#">User ID</a></th>
        <th class="table-header-repeat line-left"><a href="#">Username</a></th>
        <th class="table-header-repeat line-left"><a href="#">Firstname</a></th>
        <th class="table-header-repeat line-left"><a href="#">Lastname</a></th>
        <th class="table-header-repeat line-left"><a href="#">Email</a></th>
        <th class="table-header-repeat line-left"><a href="#">Registration Date</a></th>
        <th class="table-header-options line-left"><a href="#">Options</a></th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach($rows as $row) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['user_id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['username']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['first_name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['last_name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['registration_date']; ?></td>
        <td class="options-width">
            <a href="#" title="Edit" class="icon-1 info-tooltip"></a>
            <a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="icon-2 info-tooltip"></a>
            <a href="#" title="Save" class="icon-5 strong-text info-tooltip"></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Hope that helps :)